# simple graph with n vertices and hamiltonian cycle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

we have a simple graph with n vertices and hamiltonian cycle, prove it has 2 even subgraphs T,S such as each edge of G is at least in one of T or S.

part 2:

if n is even , prove it has 2 odd subgraphs T2 , S2 such as each edge of G is at least in one of T2 or S2.

my attempt:

i think this condition holds for this as well: every bridgeless graph with n vertices is the union of 2 even graphs

and every edge in graph with hamiltonian cycle is in a cycle

if we prove this the problem is solved but I'm stuck

Comment: What is an "even graph" and an "odd graph"?

Comment: every vertex in subgraph has odd or even degree

Comment: Obviously, if a graph $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle, then every edge of $G$ is in a cycle. The Petersen graph is bridgeless; is it the union of two "even" graphs? I'm not sure but it seems doubtful to me.

Comment: No, the Petersen graph is not the union of two even graphs. Each of the two even graphs would have to be a $2$-regular spanning subgraph, so it would have to be the union of two $5$-cycles. Also the two even subgraphs would have to have $5$ edges in common, and that's easily seen to be impossible.

Comment: It seems like $C_5$, a cycle graph on 5 vertices, is a counterexample to part $2$. Unless I misunderstand the terminology or the requirements.